# Calculating percentages based off previous value in a group_by data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

Updated post:

I want to calculate percentages based off of previous values within my groups.

This is my toy dataset (updated):

```
data_test= {'date':[1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,4,4,4,4 ], 

            'cid':[99, 99, 100, 99, 99,100,100,99,99,100,100,99,99 , 99,101, 102, 105, 107, 100,99, 100, 100], 

            'page':['page1', 'page2', 'page1', 'page2','page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page3', 'page4',
            'page6', 'page6',  'page7' ,'page8','page8', 'page8', 'page8', 'page8' ,'page9', 'page9' ,'page10'],


            'campaignset': ['c1','c1','c1','c1', 'c1', 'c2','c2','c2','c1','c1','c2', 'c1', 'c1', 'c1',
             'c2', 'c2', 'c2','c2', 'c2', 'c2','c2','c2']} 

data_test_df = pd.DataFrame(data_test)
data_drop_dups = data_test_df.drop_duplicates(['campaignset', 'date', 'page', 'cid'])
data_grouped = data_drop_dups.groupby(['campaignset', 'date', 'page']).cid.size()
data_grouped_df = pd.DataFrame(data_grouped)
```

This almost gets me there:

```
data_grouped_df['percentage'] = data_grouped_df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0] * 100)['cid']

data_grouped_df
```

But I'm getting the Percentages in the first page for the first date for the campaignset to be > 100 when the cid > 1.

The 500 needs to be a 100. For the cell below it, it should be 2/5*100, then the cell after it should be 1/5*100.

i don't think the x/x.iloc[0] is working. its just doing x.iloc[0]*100. I think...

[image]
Any insights?

To be thorough, I also do a custom sort so that page10 goes in the bottom. This part works.

```
sortlist = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4', 'page5', 'page6', 'page7', 'page8', 'page9', 'page10']

data_grouped_df = data_grouped_df.reset_index()

data_grouped_df['page'] = pd.Categorical(data_grouped_df['page'],categories=sortlist)

data_grouped_df_2 = data_grouped_df.sort_values(['campaignset','date','page'])

print(data_grouped_df_2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's great that you've provided some sample data since that makes it easier for people to understand the problem. The logic you're describing is pretty hard to follow though, so it might also be helpful to provide an example of what you'd want the final dataframe to look like

Comment: Thank you, Randy--just updated my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data doesn't quite match up with what you've shown in the image, but I think what you want is to `groupby` the `campaignset` and `date` and then divide everything within the group by the first value of the group:

```
In [138]: data_grouped_df['percentage'] = data_grouped_df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(lambda x: x/x.iloc[0] * 100)['cid']

In [139]: data_grouped_df
Out[139]:
                          cid  percentage
campaignset date page
c1          1    page1      1       100.0
                 page2      1       100.0
            2    page1      1       100.0
                 page3      1       100.0
                 page5      1       100.0
            3    page6      1       100.0
            4    page7      1       100.0
c2          2    page2      1       100.0
                 page3      1       100.0
                 page4      2       200.0
            4    page 10    1       100.0
                 page8      1       100.0
                 page9      1       100.0
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It worked for you so that's great! It's not working for me because it doesn't recognize cid as an int. It's seeing it as a str and using int() on it doesn't work. Says it can't be interpreted as an integer. TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: That suggests that you might have some cleanup to do on the `cid` column. If `data_grouped_df['cid'] = data_grouped_df['cid'].astype(int)` fails, then you've probably got some errant strings in there that you'll want to fix before running the code above.

Comment: as type int didn't work--but as type float did!! data_grouped_df['cid'] = data_grouped_df['cid'].astype(float) THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help

Comment: it's actually not quite 100% working...when the cid of the first page in the date per campaignset is > 1, the percentage is also > 100. I updated my post with details. What I want is the first percentage to be 100, so cid at the 0th position in the group to be divided by itself * 100, and then the subsequent cids to be divided by the original one at the 0th position * 100.

Comment: `x.iloc[0]` refers to the first element, which in that case is `page 10`, so everything is based off of that. When you later apply your sort, it then looks like it did the wrong thing. If you use your custom sort first so that `page8` appears first (so something like  `data_grouped_df.apply(custom_sort).groupby(level=[0,1])...` then it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Randy. Do I need to def customsort (df): and use the sort code to create a customsort function to apply over data_grouped_df? I tried that, and it didn't work, "multilevel values only valid with MultiIndex" I don't think it likes the level  = [0,1]...

Comment: Any remaining issues are just due to your dataframe not being sorted the way you're expecting. `x.iloc[0]` is going to be whatever element appears first in the `groupby` so just do whatever you need to do to get the whole thing sorted before the commands from the answer

Comment: Thank you @Randy!! It worked. I had to set_index after the sort to recreate the data as multiindex because the sort made it a rangeindex data_grouped_df_2.set_index(['campaignset', 'date', 'page'], inplace = True)

Comment: I also had to reset the index right before the sort. data_grouped_df = data_grouped_df.reset_index()